# WooCommerce user register form verification with Google's reCaptcha

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, recaptcha, user-registration

I am using the following code in functions.php to verify form submission with Google's reCaptcha

```
function adv_validate_re_captcha_field( $username, $email, $wpErrors )
{
    $remoteIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $recaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

    $response = wp_remote_post( 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', [
        'body' => [
            'secret'   => '#####################',
            'response' => $recaptchaResponse,
            'remoteip' => $remoteIP
        ]
    ] );

    $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response );
    $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

    if ( $response_code == 200 )
    {
        $result = json_decode( $response_body, true );

        if ( ! $result['success'] )
        {
            $wpErrors->add( 'recaptcha', __( 'Error message', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'adv_validate_re_captcha_field', 10, 3 );
```

It is working just fine. The problem is that I want to verify the form only on one of the pages where the form is displayed. For example, it is used on the woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php where the reCaptcha is displayed with the following code:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="###"></div>
```

I don't want to verify the form on any other page.

Answer (score 1):

Go to wp-content -> plugins -> woocommerce-> templates -> myaccount folder and copy form-login.php file into "you-child-theme-folder" -> woocommerce -> myaccount

Now you are able to edit this template, open the form-login.php file and place these two lines below where you want the captcha to be shown

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="###"></div>
```

Comment: i wasn't aware that plugins can be editable in child theme :O voov thanks man it works